# Dynamic Popup using jquery,php,mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerynew.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {       
       $('#wings').click(function(event) 
       {
           loadPopupBox();
           $('body').css('background','#333');        
       });

       $('#popupclose').click(function(event) 
       {            
           unloadPopupBox();
           $('body').css('background','white');
       });

       function loadPopupBox() 
       {  
          $('#popupbox').fadeIn("slow");
       }        

       function unloadPopupBox() 
       {
          $('#popupbox').fadeOut("normal");       
       }  
       $("#popupbox").hide();
    });

</script>

<style>
 table { border-collapse:collapse; margin-left:370px; margin-top:20px; padding:10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS; min-width:530px; }
 table th,td { border:1px solid #8AC007; }

 #popupbox {  position:fixed; _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */ background:#FFFFFF; left:472px; top:150px; 
           border:2px solid lightgray; padding:15px;  z-index:100px; font-size:15px;  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; 
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; display:none; }

 #popupclose { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#6FA5E2; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold; line-height:15px; float:right;
               cursor:pointer;  text-decoration:none; }
</style>

<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
  mysql_select_db("popupsql",$con);

  $users = mysql_query("SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM user u");  
  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users))
  $rows[] = $row;

  echo '<table>
             <tr style="background:#8AC007;color:#8A4C25;font-size:15px;">
                <th style="padding:10px;">Firstname</th>
                <th style="padding:10px;">Lastname</th>
                <th style="padding:10px;">Status</th>
             </tr>';
  foreach($rows as $row)
  { 
     echo '<tr>
               <td style="padding:5px;">'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
               <td style="padding:5px;">'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
               <td style="padding:5px;text-align:center;">
                 <a id="wings">view status</a>
                 <div class="popupbox">
                 <div style="height:30px;"><img class="popupclose" src="close.png" style="float:right;"></img></div>';
                 $grades = mysql_query('SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname,u.email,ggh.finalgrade FROM grade_grades_history ggh, user u WHERE 
                                        u.id = ggh.userid AND u.id = '.$userid.'');   

                 $rows = array();
                 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grades));
                 $rows[] = $row;
                 foreach($rows as $row)
                 {
                   echo $row['email'];
                 }
             echo '</div>
               </td>
           </tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';     
?>
```

Here is my code for displaying jQuery popup dynamically.,
The popup opens only for the first row, but i need a popup for all the users i.e.., when I click the first user view status, a popup should display his/her appropriate status.
Can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an id on the rows make it a class. You are using the id as a selector to assign the click handlers which will only apply to the first matched element.But if you change them to classes and select the class it will aqpply to all of them.

Comment: Excellent, It was working and many thanks for your help, but could i know why id takes only for the first row where as the class does, could you explain

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Classes are typically used across multiple elements that share traits while id's are then used as a more specific identifier.

Comment: Yes.. you're absolutely correct, a popup is displaying for all the rows, that's good, but not displaying with a correct userid i.e., id isn't passing to a popup window.

Comment: Friends.. can anyone suggest